# Two different anchors to expand/collapse the same div

Tags: jquery, html, anchor, expand

I have written a code that expands a div when an anchor is clicked. I want to add another anchor that expands the same div when clicked but when I add the second anchor the first one doesn't work. Is it possible that two different anchors can be used to expand the same div? If so, how can I do that? Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
<div class="Style10" id="ED">

      <h5><a href="#" id="EDA" onclick="Anchor(id)">Education</a><img id="EDI" class="Triangle" src="TriangleDown.png"></h5>

      <div>

           <h6><a href="#" id="EDAA" onclick="Anchor(id)">Add</a></h6>
           //Here I want to add the second anchor that also expands div class="Style11"
           <div class="Style11">
              ....
              some code here
              ....
           <div>

      <div>
<div>
```

The JQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#ED div').hide();

   $('#ED a').click(function(e){
        $(this).parent().next('#ED div').slideToggle('normal');
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
   });

});
```

The Anchor function:

```
 function Anchor(id) {
    if (id == "EDA") {
        if (document.getElementById("EDI").getAttribute("src") ==    "TriangleDown.png") {
            document.getElementById("EDI").src = "TriangleUp.png";
        }
        else {
           document.getElementById("EDI").src = "TriangleDown.png";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you replicate the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: What is `onclick="Anchor(id)"`?

Comment: Anchor(id) is another function that I have written

Comment: Why do you use both `onclick=...` and `.click()` for the same element ?

Comment: This appears to work for me; the Education link expands the comment, and the Add link toggles the "... some code here". But your jQuery selector IDs don't seem to match anything on the page.

Comment: @DaveNewton The problem appears when second link is added

Comment: Totally unrelated, but naming styles "Style10" or "Style11" leaves me a little cold; IMO styles should be more semantic.

Comment: svealto Is right.. The problem is when the second anchor is added.  @DaveNewton

Comment: Include the `Anchor` function, then. I don't really understand the problem or the desired behavior, I guess.

Comment: The Anchor function is used for changing an image when the div panel is epanded. What I want to do is to add an anchor "Edit" that expands the same div that "Add" anchor expands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next()` reffers to the **closest** *next* element. In your case (when you add another link), for the first link `next` will be the second link.

You could simply fix that using [**`nextAll()`**](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/) instead of [**`next()`**](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
// instead of:
// $(this).parent().next('#ED div').slideToggle('normal');
// this:
$(this).parent().nextAll('div').first().slideToggle('normal');
```

Also, there's no need to use `onclick` attribute since you have registered click event handler for the element with jQuery `$('#ED a').click(...)`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzLp2tjd/)

---

**EDIT**

If you have more stuff to handle on *click*, add it either in `click()` or `onclick` method. In this case no need to use both.

[**JSFiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzLp2tjd/2/)

Comment: Glad I could help. I have updated fiddle with your `Anchor()` method.